# C# How to specify assembly available in subfolder

Tags: c#, dacpac

I have an sqlpackage.exe and sqlpackage.exe.config.xml file in the root folder. The .config.xml is referencing ssemblies in the subfolder.  How to specify in the config to refer assemblies in subfolder named '\binaries'

Here the section in .config.xml:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="15.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="12.0.0.0-14.100.0.0" newVersion="15.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="11.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="15.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="11.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="15.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the `probing` element.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element

> Specifies subdirectories of the application's base directory that might contain assemblies. Delimit each subdirectory with a semicolon.

Example from docs:

```xml
<configuration>  
   <runtime>  
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>  
      </assemblyBinding>  
   </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

So in your case:

```xml
<configuration>  
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="binaries"/>  
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="15.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="12.0.0.0-14.100.0.0" newVersion="15.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="11.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="15.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="11.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="15.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: so in my case should it be <probing privatePath="binaries;"/>

Comment: @MukilDeepthi yes that should work. But remember this sub directory needs to be present beside the `.exe`